# Join table issue in Spring Data JPA

Tags: join, spring-data

I am trying to create a view with datas which combines two tables. I successfully implemented the join and datas are displaying properly by using spring data JPA join. Here my issue is that, when I am calling `findAll()` method from only one table, which returns all the data including joined table also,

I joined table Users model class like:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class Users implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Integer id;

@Column(name = "username")
public String username;

@Column(name = "password")
public String password;

@Column(name = "privid")
public Integer privid;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,mappedBy="pid")
public Set<Privillages> priviJoin;

public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public Integer getPrivid() {
    return privid;
}

public void setPrivid(Integer privid) {
    this.privid = privid;
}

public Set<Privillages> getPriviJoin() {
    return priviJoin;
}

public void setPriviJoin(Set<Privillages> priviJoin) {
    this.priviJoin = priviJoin;
}
public Users() {
}
}
```

And my second model Privillages like,

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Privillages")
public class Privillages implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
public Integer Id;

@Column(name = "pname")
public String pname;

@ManyToOne(optional = false)
@JoinColumn(name = "pid", referencedColumnName = "privid")
public Users pid;

public Integer getId() {
    return Id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    Id = id;
}

public String getPname() {
    return pname;
}

public void setPname(String pname) {
    this.pname = pname;
}

public Users getPid() {
    return pid;
}

public void setPid(Users pid) {
    this.pid = pid;
}
public Privillages(){
}
}
```

And repository containing,

```
@Query("select u from Users u JOIN FETCH u.priviJoin p")
Set<Users> findByUsername();
```

These are all my codes, here i added. The thing is that, join is properly working with expected resultset. But when I call findAll() method , the it returns all the structure including both joined table.

I called my findAll function like,

```
@RequestMapping("/check")
    public List<Users> check() {
                        return (List<Users>) userRepo.findAll();
    }
```

But result is like I previously mentioned.Here I added its screenshot,

[image]

In this figure we can see that it returns the both table values instead of users table data.

Why is it happening like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You defined your domain type `Users` to contain a reference so it gets loaded as specified.

If you want something similar to a `Users` object but without the reference, you have two options:

1. Change the `Users` type to not contain a reference.
2. Use a different type, similar to `Users` but without the reference. There are multiple ways to do that, but probably the simplest and most helpful in the current situation is to use a projection. See https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections